# Jquery Filer adding header

Tags: javascript, jquery, header

We have following problem, we really need to add header in object (uploadFile) : and we can't recive it..

```
uploadFile: {
   url: SERWER+"person/offer/photo/upload",
   data: null,
   type: 'POST',
   enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
   synchron: true,
   headers : {
          'X-Auth-Token' : localStorage.getItem('X-Auth-Token')
      },
   success: function(data, itemEl, listEl, boxEl, newInputEl, inputEl, id){
      console.log(data);
```

It doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you better-define "doesn't work"?

Comment: http request is always sending without headers

Comment: How are you reading the headers? What headers do you get (you should have some)? What value do you get from `localStorage.getItem('X-Auth-Token')`? What headers do you see being sent in the network panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add headers to jQuery.filer. You can try using `beforeSend`:

```
var beforeSendFn = function(){
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader('X-Auth-Token', localStorage.getItem('X-Auth-Token'));
}

uploadFile: {
   beforeSend: beforeSendFn
   ...
}
```